# Highmaps - show a bubble per continent

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I have a JSON with countries and a sum of money per country,
I want to group all countries in continents and show a bubbles over the continents with a sum of countries' money. How I can do it?

Comment: If you have a lookup of country to continent then sum up and create series to add to continent map?

Comment: How your data does it look like ? Could you recreate your example on the jsfiddle.net ?